# C# break debugger on exception as "Break When Thrown"

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-debugging

In my asp.net application if exception is thrown by application it is caught and 500 page is served instead. I would like to break debugger at throw location. Currently I am using following code snippet:

```
           void ExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
                if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }}
```

However this code breaks at `ExceptionHandler`, not at throw location. How can I break at throw location?

I do not want to change exception settings, because I want to break on exceptions that reached `ExceptionHandler`, not on exceptions that system recovered from.

To better illustrate my problem:

```
class Server // Server owned by third party
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (source, e) =>
        {
            // This does not help, because there are legit exceptions
            Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: \"{1}\"",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
        };
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (source, e) =>
        {
            // This does not help, because exception should be handled by server, otherwise it would shut down
            Console.WriteLine("UnhandledException event raised in {0}: \"{1}\"",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.ExceptionObject);
        };

        var app = new Application();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                app.ProcessRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // If we get here this mean that something is wrong with application
                // Let's break on line marked as #1
                Console.WriteLine("Server swallowed an exception \"{0}\"", e.Message);
                Debugger.Break(); // Debugger breaks, but no exception dialog, and stack trace in method main
            }
        }
    }
}

class Application
{
    public void ProcessRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Legit exception handled by application");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application handled exception \"{0}\"", ex.Message);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled exception"); // #1. Something is wrong here
    }
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Doing stuff
FirstChanceException event raised in ExceptionTest: "Legit exception handled by application"
Application handled exception "Legit exception handled by application"
FirstChanceException event raised in ExceptionTest: "Unhandled exception"
Server swallowed an exception "Unhandled exception"
```

Comment: The debugger will always break at `Debugger.Break();` or at the point where an exception is thrown and no one is catching it. You should, if you have something like: `try { ... } catch { /* dang! */ ExceptionHandler(); }`, still see the stack trace though, which should lead you to the original exception. I would pass the exception to the `ExceptionHandler` also, to make sure that it is readily available for analysis. Last note: this may not be the best way of achieving what you want, what's the end goal exactly?

Comment: I would like to replace `Debugger.Break();` with something that works better. My goal is to break on exceptions that are handled by global exception handlers. But not just break, but break with exception context.

Comment: Doesn't `Debugger.Break();` break with context? I'm fairly certain that it gives you the stack trace in whichever debugging program you're using?

Comment: Something threw that exception, so something is wrong in line where is `throw` statement, nothing is wrong in line containing `Debugger.Break()`. I am not going to debug exception handler, but class that generates these exceptions.

Comment: @user2029276, Actually we often enable the Exception settings, as you don't want to use this way, you could check all Exception Handling best practices here:https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/, maybe you could get the way you want to use there.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT added code snippet to question to better illustrate my problem. Everything from article You linked happens BEFORE my problem manifests. I am talking about final exception handler that catches everything, so server process won't stop, but I want to break there if I have debugger attached.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Exception settings do not make me happy, because there are dozens of throws that are legit, and are subsequently handler by server, however there is small fraction of cases when error is Unhanded - and only this is where I want to break my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

That’s called a first chance exception handler. Here’s an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException +=
        (object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
        };

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Super awesome exception");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught an exception {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Or see this in the msdn docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-receive-first-chance-exception-notifications

The callstack when the firstchance exception is hit will show the “throw” as the previous location on the callstack.

**Update:**

Second chance exceptions don’t get handled during the “throw”. That’s by definition. The stacktrace has the throw location.

So you can either
-   Break on first chance and ignore the exceptions you don’t care about (just rethrow them)
-   Break on second chance exceptions and inspect the stack trace to determine where they came from

You can’t break on the “throw” with a second chance handler. That’s not how they work.

Comment: Thanks for Your help, however this is not what I want. I would like to break on "second-chance exception", but from perspective of server code. In other words - there are execptions that my application can recover from and I want to ignore these. That is why `FirstChanceException` is not for me. Updated question code to better illustrate this issue.

Comment: @user2029276, I updated my answer, you could check it:)

Comment: `Break on first chance and ignore the exceptions you don’t care about` - I cannot, because I am only interested in exceptions, that had no matching catch, and this is determined after first pass.

`Break on second chance exceptions and inspect the stack trace to determine where they came from` - this is what I have now, however it is much better experience working on console application, because second chance exceptions are handled nicely. In server scenarios You have to fight this behavior.

Comment: @user2029276, Those are the solution I could provide now, no other good suggestions. But if you have other suggestions or feedback, you could submit a user voice to the product team directly: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Answer (score -1):

You could attach the Visual Studio Debugger (or Remote Debugger if it is running on a separate machine).

Step 1: Configure settings within the Visual Studio IDE.

From the menu bar, select Debug > Windows >  Exception Settings.

If you select all exceptions, this will cause the debugger to break *before* each exception (handled and unhandled) while you are attached to the running process.

Step 2: Attach to your process to debug it within Visual Studio (local or remote).

From the menu bar, select Debug > Attach to process... then locate your application or web app pool by process id.

(Note: If you are remote debugging, then copy the Remote Debugger from your install directory of Visual Studio to the remote machine and run it at Administrator so Visual Studio can connect.  Typically it defaults to port 4020.)

Comment: I just pointed out that I do not want to change `Exception Settings`.